# password less sudo

Tags: sudo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [a safer no password sudo?](https://superuser.com/questions/213690/a-safer-no-password-sudo)

I'm trying to do a physical to virtual using the "VMWare VCenter Converter Standalone". The Convert Machine Window provides a the option to provide source ip, username, password, and the OS family. It tries to query the remote machine with all these information, but then shows the message.

**Unable to query the live Linux source machine. Please make sure that you can execute sudo without entering a password when logged in to the source machine over SSH as 'username'**

How do I configure the 'username' account to do sudo without a password? 
(and err ... still sleep peacefully :P)

Comment: Duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/213690/a-safer-no-password-sudo

Comment: I disagree that the linked http://superuser.com/questions/213690/a-safer-no-password-sudo is a duplicate. the linked question is asking about "is my password the problem...". this question is just asking. "how do you use sudo without password?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the sudoers file add the NOPASSWD: tag infront of the commands you want to be able to use.

If the user is in the admin group, and you want the user to run all commands without a password you want:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

The admin line without the NOPASSWD: is probably already there - just insert the NOPASSWD: bit.

Obviously modify this for your own particular setup.

Comment: yeah ... worked.

Comment: It's same used in AMS EC2 default users. Nice trick when password sharing is risky